# Rails before_action to allow all actions from a resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The routes.rb contain:

```
...
resources :mystuff
...
```

the application_controller contain:

```
...
before_action :check_login, except: [:login, :auth]
...
```

On the login page I have a `link_to mystuff_path` that never happens.
The problem is that I want to allow all actions in `mystuff` regardless of login-status.
How do I need to modify the `before_action` to allow that? (Using Ruby 2.3.1, Rails 5.2.6)

I've tried:

```
...
before_action :do_stuff
...
def do_stuff
  check_login unless mystuff_path || login_path || auth_path
end
...
```

which allows mystuff-actions and normal login, but causes `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken`, which I think is unrelated (to this one) problem to be solved. Also I don't know what else may be clobbered this way, e.g.: validation? ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `skip_before_action` to skip a callback. For example:

```
class ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user! # secure by default
end

class PostsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user! # opt out of authentication for this controller
end
```

It takes the same `only`, `except`, `if` and `unless` options as `before_action` which can be used for more fine grained control:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:show, :index]
end

class PostsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, unless: :some_condition?
end
```

Comment: looks promising, I'll test (strange I was never notified of your answer!?)